# Updating a column in Postgres only returning one value incorrectly (Postgres 9.5.1)

Tags: postgresql

Suppose I have a table created by the following:

```
create table test.sales
(
 customer text,
 purchased text,
 date_purchased date,
 rownumber integer,
 primary key (customer, date_purchased)
)
;

insert into test.sales
values
('kevin', 'books', '2017-01-01'::date, null),
('kevin', 'movies', '2017-01-02'::date, null),
('paul', 'books', '2017-01-05'::date, null),
('paul', 'movies', '2017-01-07'::date, null)
```

At this point, `rownumber` is always `NULL` and I want to set the value of `rownumber` with `row_number() over (partition by customer order by date_purchased) as rownumber`. The way I am going about this is the following:

```
update test.sales as a
set (rownumber) =
(
select
  row_number() over (partition by customer order by date_purchased) as rownumber
from test.sales as b
-- These fields correspond to the primary keys of the table.
where a.customer = b.customer
  and a.date_purchased = b.date_purchased
)
```

But for some reason this returned:

```
customer    purchased   date_purchased  rownumber
kevin        books         1/1/17          1
kevin        movies        1/2/17          1
paul         books         1/5/17          1
paul         movies        1/7/17          1
```

I'm expecting this:

```
customer    purchased   date_purchased  rownumber
kevin        books         1/1/17          1
kevin        movies        1/2/17          2
paul         books         1/5/17          1
paul         movies        1/7/17          2
```

Notice that in the actual results, `rownumber` is always 1. Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

You are ussing a scalar subquery. Use a correlated subquery instead:

---

```
UPDATE test.sales dst
SET rownumber = src.rownumber
FROM    ( SELECT customer,date_purchased
        , row_number() over (partition by customer order by date_purchased) as rownumber
        from test.sales 
        ) src
WHERE dst.customer = src.customer
  AND dst.date_purchased = src.date_purchased
        ;
```

Comment: Interesting! Should I potentially be worried about efficiency/scalability? My understanding is that correlated subqueries don't work well with large number of rows.

Comment: Test it. (at least the result is correct, so the test is kind of useless anyway ...)